# Problema con a href y .preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente código:

```js
function boton_mas(){
 event.preventDefault();
}

window.addEventListener('mousedown',boton_mas,false);

window.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
 window.removeEventListener('mousedown',boton_mas,false);
 boton_mas(e);
},false);
```

```html
<a class="ripple" href="http://www.google.es">VER MÁS</a>
```

El problema es el siguiente. Mi sitio utiliza ajax para proporcionar una mayor experiencia de usuario el problema es el SEO y con la intención de mejorarlo he decidido por introducir los enlaces como un sitio normal y luego anularlo mediante javascript ademas asi me ayuda a crear una alternativa a mi sitio para quien tenga desactivado javascript en el navegador. Bueno el caso es que con mousedown y touchstart preventDefault() no funciona solo lo hace con el evento click y mi pregunta es que seria mas optimo substituir el enlace por javascript:void(0); o crear un evento nuevo con la funcion click (y mantener los eventos mousedown y touchstart para el efecto ripple) pensando desde el punto de vista del rendimiento.

Comment: te esta faltando pasarle el evento al preventdefault onda: `function boton_mas(evento){ evento.preventDefault(); return false }` aunque funciona mejor en el onclick , prevenis el default del evento, haces tu ajax ( usando evento.target para saber cual es el que dispara el evento) y luego retornar false

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que para poder prevenir el evento, deberías pasar el evento a la función que lo trata.

Además, el eventListener deberías asignárselo al botón/elemento que está lanzando el evento, no a window.

Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('a');
const preventLinks = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Enlace Prevenido');
}

button.addEventListener('click', preventLinks);
button.addEventListener('mouseDown', preventLinks);
```

```html
<a class="ripple" href="http://www.google.es">VER MÁS</a>
```